# Codeigniter controller multiple return when each result is ready

Tags: php, codeigniter

My controller is like this.

```
public function fetch_all_catagories()
              {
                  {  $output1 = '';
                   
                    $this->load->model('Pharmacy_model');
                    $data = $this->Pharmacy_model->fetch_main_catagories();
                    $output .='<option value=0>All</option>';
                    if($data->num_rows()>0){
                          
                        foreach($data->result() as $row){
                         
                                $output1 .='    
                                                  <option value='.$row->id.'>'.$row->category_name.'</option>';
            
                                
                            }
                           }
                           else {               
                           }
                           
                          $main_catagory =  $output1;
                }

                {
                  $output2 = '';
                 
                  $this->load->model('Pharmacy_model');
                  $data = $this->Pharmacy_model->fetch_sub_catagories();
                  $output .='<option value=0>All</option>';
                  if($data->num_rows()>0){
                        
                      foreach($data->result() as $row){
                       
                              $output2 .='    
                                                <option value='.$row->category_id.'>'.$row->category_name.'</option>';
          
                              
                          }
                         }
                         else {               
                         }
                         
                         $sub_catagory =  $output2;
              }

              {
                $output3 = '';
               
                $this->load->model('Pharmacy_model');
                $data = $this->Pharmacy_model->fetch_serving_types();
                $output .='<option value=0>All</option>';
                if($data->num_rows()>0){
                      
                    foreach($data->result() as $row){
                     
                            $output3 .='    
                                              <option value='.$row->id.'>'.$row->serving_type.'</option>';
        
                            
                        }
                       }
                       else {               
                       }
                       
                       $serving_types =  $output3;
            }

            {
              $output4 = '';
              
              $this->load->model('Pharmacy_model');
              $data = $this->Pharmacy_model->fetch_approved_suppliers_alternate_names();
              $output .='<option value=0>All</option>';
              if($data->num_rows()>0){
                    
                  foreach($data->result() as $row){
                    
                          $output4 .='    
                                            <option value='.$row->id.'>'.$row->suppier_alternate_name.'</option>';
      
                          
                      }
                      }
                      else {               
                      }
                      
                      $suppliers =  $output4;
          }  

          $data  = array('main_catagory' =>$main_catagory, 'sub_catagory' =>$sub_catagory, 'serving_types' =>$serving_types, 'suppliers' =>$suppliers);
               echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

My question is, rather than returning all results in one array, is there any way to return data one by one when the function is executed. Which means it doesn't need to wait until all the functions are executed, when a function is completed, it returns data to the view and so on.

Comment: The simplest might be to use JS AJAX from your front end.  Make 4 AJAX requests, each one for just one of those results.  The JS on your front end can then handle the results as they come back, asynchronously.  But having said that, AFAICT you are just loading categories from the DB, unless you have millions of categories, those queries should all be very fast?  Why do you want them done separately?

Comment: Dont use capitol letters when you call the model. Also put your model in the config->autoload file then you dont need to keep calling it. Our load it at the top of your class

Comment: @Don'tPanic I did try separate AJAX calls from front end, but due to the poor internet connection, it took long time to load all the data. That's why I'm using this. I just wanted to load them separately as it will bit improve the performance rather than transferring a large amount of data at one time.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your help. I'll do so. Is there any performance difference with autoload and this?

Comment: There is no difference in performance in autloading vs loading from a controller, just 1 less line of code - it only [makes sense to autoload](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#auto-loading-models) if you are loading that model everywhere, eg every controller.  However, there is definitely no need to load it 4x in one controller method (is it one method? You have strange `{}` around each code block, are they really different methods?).  Do it once/method, or if you're doing it in every method, do it in your 1/Controller (in the constructor).

Comment: @Don'tPanic Here it is a single method with 4 calls to the same model but different functions. So i think it's better to add the method call in the constructor. Isn't it?

Comment: You have 1 function, 1 method. I've never seen this construction before `public function method() {  {some code;} {more code;} {more code;}  }`.  It strangely works ... but all that code is still in the same function/method.  You only need to load the model once there.  Whether it is in the controller or method doesn't make any difference.

Comment: When you create a function, it should do one thing. Keep them simple. Remember, you can call another function within a function. Also, there is no penalty for auto loading a model

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just randomly tried that multi code function due to the poor internet connection of the client to reduce the number of AJAX requests to the server and it worked. That's why I tried to make a single AJAX request and populate multiple drop downs. For maximum user experience, I just wanted to know whether I can load the first drop down that user uses, then the second and so on but still with a single AJAX request.

Comment: Not without doing some websocket-type stuff, I guess.  Think about it - the jQuery `success` callback runs when the request is *complete*.  Maybe you could try writing the XMLHttpRequest JS manually and using [the `progress` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event) to watch the transferred data and use each chunk as it comes?  But this seems like serious overkill, if the client's connection is that bad they will have trouble on every page, there does not seem much point in a complex fix to improve a few `<select>`s.